# Using VBA to place the sum of all numbers above selected cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm seeking for help in using VBA to place a sum of all cells which type is numbers/value above selected cell and can apply for everywhere but not fix in specific sheet or some ranges in the sheet. The VBA have the same function as the excel shortcut "Atl +".

Note: auto sum all cell have numbers/value above but not for the entire column; or you can understand that code is to sum up until blank. Look at my embedded image. My selected cell is yellow.

[image: Example]

Thank you so much and best regards

Comment: Any reason you want to write a function for something that already is build in? And what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Hi sir, actually, I want to create another formula based on this function and this step is the most important. That function will make my work faster. I am bad at VBA so I decided to seek help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.END(xlup)` to determine the last cell before blank upwards.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you so much, I found the way ^^

Comment: If my answer works for you, I would appreciate if you could mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark to the left. Or if you found a different way of solving it, you can post it as an answer yourself to help others.